# How to calculate offsets with an array from sub-array sizes, in parallel?

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, gpgpu

I have an array of data structures, sorted in blocks of different size within the array.
An algorithm extracts from it few of the data structures, and stores that in a new one. It also counts how many it took from each block. However, near-unsynchronizable nature of compute shaders causes the resulting array to be unsorted. I want to make a new one that would use the knowledge of new block sizes (how many the algorithm took from each in the past), to sort them. However, while I know sizes of blocks, I don't know offsets within the array, where each block should start. I could easily do it on CPU, but everything happens within a GPU - its a pre-processing of graphics inputs, a huge number of them, and communicating back and forth, waiting for CPU in a middle of the frame, is expensive.

How do I calculate said offsets efficiently within a GPU shader? This seems like a parallel reduction problem to me, however requiring to save intermediate results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For NVIDIA GPUs, you can find libraries and code for a parallel “prefix sum” in both thrust and CUB. If you store your block sizes in an array, then a prefix sum on that array should give you the offset for each block.

CUB: https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_scan.html

Thrust: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html#prefix-sums